# How can I Create a generic method for these?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

Please how can I create method for each of these two generic list of Fragments??

As constructor won't allow me to create multiple
Of these methods.

1. I want to create a method that looks like the constructor ****Semesters (int position){
   mData=getCsList(position);
   }****

When I run the program my constructor is called by the compiler, which does the job I want it. How can I achieve this by creating and using methods that does same Job because I have many list of Fragments,and as to contractor will not allow me due to it's parameters signature,that's why I want to use methods and keep the same signature throughout. Thanks

................... EDIT CODE.......…..

SemesterFragment.java

```
 package com.example.viewpager2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator;

public class SemesterFragment extends Fragment {
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager2 viewPager2;
    MyViewPager adapter;

    public SemesterFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_semester, container, false);
        viewPager2 = (ViewPager2) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager2);
        tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        adapter = new MyViewPager(getChildFragmentManager(), this.getLifecycle());
        viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);
        new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                tab.setText("Sem" + (position + 1));
            }
        }).attach();
        addComputerScienceSem();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return view;
    }

    private void addComputerScienceSem() {
        adapter.addFrags(new Semesters().newInstance(0, 1));
        adapter.addFrags(new Semesters().newInstance(0, 2));
        adapter.addFrags(new Semesters().newInstance(0, 3));
        adapter.addFrags(new Semesters().newInstance(0, 4));
    }
}
```

MyViewPager.java

```
package com.example.viewpager2;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyViewPager extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyViewPager(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrags(Fragment fragment) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
    }
}
```

Semesters.java

```
 package com.example.viewpager2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Semesters extends Fragment {
    List mData;
    RVFragment adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public Semesters() {
    }

    public static Semesters newInstance(int index, int position) {
        Semesters fragment = new Semesters();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", index);
        args.putInt("position", position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new RVFragment(getContext(), mData);
        if (getArguments().getInt("index", 0) == 0) {
            mData = getCSList(getArguments().getInt("position", 0));
        } else if (getArguments().getInt("index", 0) == 1) {
            mData = getSTAList(getArguments().getInt("position", 0));
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }

    private List getCSList(int position) {
        List list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (position == 0) { //fragment one inside viewpager whenever item1 is clicked from the recyclerView 
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("intro. to comp", "com101", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("digital electonics", "com112", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("intro to programming", "com113", "4"));
        } else if (position == 1) { //fragment two inside viewpager whenever item1 is clicked from the recyclerView 
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem2", "com111", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem2", "com222", "5"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem2", "com121", "4"));
        } else if (position == 2) { //fragment three inside viewpager whenever item1 is clicked from the recyclerView 
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem3", "com111", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem3", "com222", "5"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem3", "com121", "4"));
        } else if (position == 3) { //fragment four inside viewpager whenever item1 is clicked from the recyclerView 
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem4", "com111", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem4", "com222", "5"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem4", "com121", "4"));
        }
        return list;
    }

    private List getSTAList(int position) {
        List list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (position == 4) { //fragment one inside viewpager whenever item2 is clicked from the recyclerView 
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("probability", "STA 111", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("algebra", "STA 112", "4"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("logic", "STA 113", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("geometri func", "STA 114", "4"));
        } else if (position == 5) { //fragment two inside viewpager whenever item2 is clicked from the recyclerView 
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("set theory", "STA 111", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("dedvwvdv", "STA 112", "4"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("fbcfvdv", "STA 113", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("cvsvsdvs", "STA 114", "4"));
        } else if (position == 6) { //fragment three inside viewpager whenever item2 is clicked from the recyclerView 
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("geo", "STA 111", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("semdvbv3", "STA 112", "4"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("dedgsedv", "STA 113", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("frgs", "STA 114", "4"));
        } else if (position == 7) { //fragment four inside viewpager whenever item2 is clicked from the recyclerView 
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("log", "STA 111", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem4fff", "STA 112", "4"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem4gtgg", "STA 113", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem4uku", "STA 114", "4"));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

...................EDITED this……........

DepartmentRVAdapter.java

```
 public void onClick(View v){


    clickInterface.onItemClickListener(getLayoutPosition());
        switch(getAdapterPosition()){
        //loads department best on the position that user click
        case 0:                         // it loads all departments in the school
        Objects.requireNonNull(departmentFragment.getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction() //
        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.exit_to_right)
        .replace(R.id.frameLayout,new SemesterFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();break;

     case 1:                         // it loads all departments in the school
        
Objects.requireNonNull(departmentFragment.getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction() //
        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.exit_to_right)
        .replace(R.id.frameLayout,new SemesterFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();break;

}
```

Comment: Formatted well, good to go

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why you cannot use the same constructor. Declare another field called mData2 like this after mData1

```
public class Semesters extendss Fragment{ 
List<SemesterModelClass> mData;
List<SemesterModelClass> mData2;
```

Now call `mData2 = getStaList(position);` in the constructor like this

```
public Semesters(int position) {
    mData = getCsList(position);
    mData2 = getStaList(position);
}
```

---------------------- EDIT ----------------------

Set the ViewPager to work like this. Use a static method like this. 0 for the first page and 1 for the second

```
public class Semesters extendss Fragment {
    List < SemesterModelClass > mData;

    public static Semesters newInstance(int index, int position) {

        Semesters f = new Semesters();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", index);
        args.putInt("postion", postion);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (getArguments().getInt("index", 0) == 0) {
            mData = getCsList(getArguments().getInt("position", 0))
        } else if (getArguments().getInt("index", 0) == 1) {
            mData = getStaList(getArguments().getInt("position", 0))
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: '@Robin, i appreciate,Going by this It will work but I have a viewpager that holds 4 frags, and when I called this constructor **public Semesters(int position) {
    mData = getCsList(position)
    mData2 = getStaList(position)** inside viewpager it will populate 8 frags instead to add only 4 frags either this **getCsList(position) or getStaList(position)** , why I want to do this is that, I want if the user click on item1 in a recycler view it will take getCsList(position) and populates to 4 frags inside viewpager, and if item2 is clicked then it will take getStaList(position) and populates

Comment: Have edited the code to have space for dynamic positions with fragment arguments

Comment: I have edited the code,  but where could I use it?? Above Is the complete code pls help

Comment: The idea here is to not call new Semester() directly but to call the static method to help instantiate the class and return it. call `Semester.newInstace(getLayoutPosition(), position)` notice that the postion is the same but the list populated will be different based on the adapter position index. Is there a reason you are using getLayoutPosition() rather than getAdapterPosition()?

Comment: DepartmentRVAdapter.java ??   I tried using getAdapterPosition() in placed of getLayoutPosition() but it couldn't work. Say, **case:0(i.e Item1 from RV),then populates getCSList(...)**, If **case:1 (Item2 from RV) then populates getStaList (...)**